# Getting the Derby database connection is very slow from Ubuntu to Windows and vice versa

Tags: derby

I am new bie to Apache Derby, I have been asked to test the performance of Derby database with 1000 concurrent threads, In each thread, open a connection, do one insert, select, update queries on one table.

I implemented the simulation code and tested on my local machine (Windows 7) where I am running my Derby database in networking mode.

Even I tested the same from another Windows 7 machine (Only Java Client, DB is running in my machine only) from my LAN.

When I am testing above simulation from Ubuntu system, I am facing a lot of issues. For opening each connection, it is taking 5xxx milliseconds, where as in other scenarios it is 2xx milliseconds.

If I am simulating upto 1000 threads means the time also increasing to get each connection. Typically it is above 60000 milliseconds.

I observed that from wireshark is listing the follwoing error in case of Ubuntu system.

- Protocol : ICMP
- Info : Destination unreachable (Port unreachable).

Surprisingly when I installed Kaspersky in ubuntu machine I am not getting this error. I am able to get connection with in 3xx milliseconds like that.

I tried with implementing the connection pool (Tomcat pool, DBCP, C3p0) also.

In any case with out antivirus in ubuntu machine it is taking too much time to get the connection and i am seeing the above error in Wireshark.

Please help me in this what could be catch here ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly sounds like a networking problem. Have you tried investigating with lower-level tools, such as ping, netstat, traceroute, etc.?

In particular, look for name resolution problems between the two systems, as those often cause networking slowdowns like these. Is each machine able to perform a reverse DNS lookup (get-name-by-address call)?